# Several exclusion criteria SUMIFS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is my Excel table:

```
Apple        5
Apricot      3
Avocado      8
Banana       10
Bilberry     3
Blackberry   2
Blackcurrant 15
Blueberry    2
Boysenberry  7
```

I would like to sum everything except Apricot and Banana.

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B9,A1:A9,"<>Apricot&<>Banana")
```

But the returned sum is 55 and not 42.

It is working fine if I only write:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B9,A1:A9,"<>Apricot")
```

Any idea of how I can manage this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the AND form by asking for the criteria as two different entries.

This is saying sum all of B where A is not equal to `Banana` ***AND*** not equal to `Apricot`

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<>Banana",A:A,"<>Apricot")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott. The thing is I would like to store the exclusion condition in a text cell. For example `'<>Apricot&<>Banana`. Then use the reference of the cell in `SUMIFS`.

Comment: That is not what you asked.

Comment: Yes you're right my question was not precise enough. Anyway your solution is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To update Scott's answer: 
`=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<>"&E1,A:A,"<>"&F1)` 
will allow you to write the criteria you want to exclude in cell E1 and F1.